# How to send json message body in aws SNS using console

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am doing a hands on where I want to add an SNS trigger to a lambda function which then sends a message to a slack channel. There is a blueprint for this lambda in python and also a template test event which looks like the following

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:EXAMPLE",
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "Sns": {
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "Signature": "EXAMPLE",
        "SigningCertUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "MessageId": "12345",
        "Message": {
          "AlarmName": "SlackAlarm",
          "NewStateValue": "OK",
          "NewStateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (0.0) was not greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0)."
        },
        "MessageAttributes": {
          "Test": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "TestString"
          },
          "TestBinary": {
            "Type": "Binary",
            "Value": "TestBinary"
          }
        },
        "Type": "Notification",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:EXAMPLE",
        "Subject": "TestInvoke"
      }
    }
  ]
```

The code in lambda handler from the blueprint is as follows

```
import boto3
import json
import logging
import os

from base64 import b64decode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

HOOK_URL = os.environ['kmsEncryptedHookUrl']
SLACK_CHANNEL = os.environ['slackChannel']

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Event: " + str(event))
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    logger.info("Message: " + str(message))

    alarm_name = message['AlarmName']
    new_state = message['NewStateValue']
    reason = message['NewStateReason']

    slack_message = {
        'channel': SLACK_CHANNEL,
        'text': "%s state is now %s: %s" % (alarm_name, new_state, reason)
    }

    req = Request(HOOK_URL, json.dumps(slack_message).encode('utf-8'))
    try:
        response = urlopen(req)
        response.read()
        logger.info("Message posted to %s", slack_message['channel'])
    except HTTPError as e:
        logger.error("Request failed: %d %s", e.code, e.reason)
    except URLError as e:
        logger.error("Server connection failed: %s", e.reason)
```

When I run the test event, the lambda runs successfully.

I wanted to publish a message in SNS topic from the console to see if the lambda is triggered correctly. But when I try to publish the JSON object as a message body, I am getting the error

```
[ERROR] TypeError: string indices must be integersTraceback (most recent call last):  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 21, in lambda_handler    alarm_name = message['AlarmName']
```

I tried giving plain json

```
{
  "AlarmName": "PublishedAlarm",
  "NewStateValue": "OK",
  "NewStateReason": "This alarm is published"
}
```

I tried giving a stringified JSON

```
"{\"AlarmName\": \"PublishedAlarm\",\"NewStateValue\": \"OK\",\"NewStateReason\": \"This alarm is published\"}"
```

I tried choosing `Custom payload for each delivery` message structure and then gave the following message body

```
{
  "default": "Sample fallback message",
  "email": "Sample message for email endpoints",
  "sqs": "Sample message for Amazon SQS endpoints",
  "lambda": "{\"AlarmName\": \"PublishedAlarm\",\"NewStateValue\": \"OK\",\"NewStateReason\": \"This alarm is published\"}",
  "http": "Sample message for HTTP endpoints",
  "https": "Sample message for HTTPS endpoints",
  "sms": "Sample message for SMS endpoints",
  "firehose": "Sample message for Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose endpoints",
  "APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Sample message for iOS endpoints\"} }",
  "APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Sample message for iOS development endpoints\"}}",
  "APNS_VOIP": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Sample message for Apple VoIP endpoints\"}}",
  "APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Sample message for Apple VoIP development endpoints\"} }",
  "MACOS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Sample message for MacOS endpoints\"}}",
  "MACOS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Sample message for MacOS development endpoints\"} }",
  "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Sample message for Android endpoints\" } }",
  "ADM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Sample message for FireOS endpoints\" } }",
  "BAIDU": "{\"title\":\"Sample message title\",\"description\":\"Sample message for Baidu endpoints\"}",
  "MPNS": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\"><wp:Tile><wp:Count>ENTER COUNT</wp:Count><wp:Title>Sample message for Windows Phone 7+ endpoints</wp:Title></wp:Tile></wp:Notification>",
  "WNS": "<badge version=\"1\" value=\"42\"/>"
}
```

Nothing worked. I've also subscribed an email address to the topic and I'm getting emails without any issues.

How can I simulate the test event given in lambda event templates from the SNS?

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Still persists?

Comment: @Marcin I used `json` instead of `ast.literal_eval` as you suggested. But yes, parsing the message in lambda handler worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you send your plain json message using SNS, it will be delivered to lambda in in the format:

```
'Message': '{\n  "AlarmName": "PublishedAlarm",\n  "NewStateValue": "OK",\n  "NewStateReason": "This alarm is published"\n}'
```

You can parse it using [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)' `literal_eval` method:

```
import ast

#...
#...

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Event: " + str(event))
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    logger.info("Message: " + str(message))

    message = ast.literal_eval(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])

    alarm_name = message['AlarmName']
    new_state = message['NewStateValue']
    reason = message['NewStateReason']

#...
#...
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `json.loads` instead of parsing with `ast`?

Comment: @Harry The msg body is not a valid json, and `json.loads` will fail to parse it.